# Reading secret variable out of Azure Key Vault Task from a variable

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to obtain a secret out of my KeyVault.
The variable name is secretVar.

Obtaining the secret like this: $(secretVar) works fine however I would like to retrieve it from a variable like this:

[image]

I keep getting command not found and I've no idea why this shouldn't be working.

So the name of the secret I want to extract is inside a bash variable. For this question I've simplified the problem but in my real use case I have a bash for loop which loops through secret names and inside the for loop I want to extract the appropriate value from the KeyVault with the corresponding secret name like this:

```
for secretname in secrets; do
  echo $($secretname) # This should contain the value of the secret but gives command not found
done
```

If anyone has an idea what could be happening, any help is very appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Did you also use the [az keyvault secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az_keyvault_secret_list) commands in your script? Can you share your complete bash script?

Comment: this answer helped me to resolve the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/73955440/16099218

Answer (score 0):

Look at the syntax you're using.

```
variable=secretVar
```

You are creating an environment variable with the literal value `secretVar`

Then you try to execute the value of the variable `$variable` with `$($variable)`. So it tries to run the command `secretVar`, which obviously doesn't exist, and you get an error message.

The syntax you're looking for is

```
variable=$(secretVar)
```

just like you used in the first `echo` command in the script.

If you don't want to run the variable value as a command, the syntax would be `$variable`, not `$($variable)`

`$variable` is the syntax for a Bash environment variable.

`$(variable)` is the syntax for referencing Azure DevOps variables.

Comment: Hi, the thing that I want to achieve is to get specific secrets from the keyvault which names are defined in bash variables. So that's what I tried to illustrate with a simple example. I'm sorry if I was unclear. It's not entirely clear for me why $($variable) executes a command and it doesn't reference the azure devops variable with the literal stored in $variable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the [script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#script) keyword is a shortcut for the command-line task. The task runs a script using cmd.exe on Windows and Bash on other platforms. You need to pay attention to the agent you are using.

If you want to set variables in scripts, you can use task.setvariable logging command. For example:

```
- script: |
    echo $(secretvar)
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=variable]$(secretvar)"
- script: |
    echo $(variable)
```

You can find more detailed information in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cshell#set-variables-in-scripts).

Comment: Hi, the problem that I want to access secret which names are defined in bash variables.
Trying the below gives the same problem: 

 `code - script: | 
    echo $(secretvar)
   bashvar=secretvar
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=variable]$($bashvar)"
- script: |
    echo $(variable)`

Comment: You do not need to use bashvar=secretvar. Please use task.setvariable command to set it:code - script: |      echo $(secretvar)    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=bashvar]$(secretvar)" - script: |     echo $(bashvar)

Comment: For my specific need I do need to access secrets which are defined in a bash for loop, I just gave a simplified example in questions with a starting point of defining a variable inside a bash variable.

Comment: Do you still have issues about setting variables? You can add more details in your question. Feel free to let me know if you're still blocked, I'll try my best to help.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help!, I'm still stuck I've tried to elaborate more on my question