# AzureKeyVault@2 Task & retrieve key vault value retrieval by variable?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So I have a variable in a variables.yaml file called `keyVaultSecretToRetrieve`. It can vary based on environment. Previously this pipeline was coded for single environment. So lets say the `keyVaultSecretToRetrieve` is "secret1". If in the task I put `SecretsFilter: "secret1"` and run the task and try to reference `$(secret1)` in the following task everything works great.

But my problem is that if I put it like the example below as `SecretsFilter $(keyVaultSecretToRetrieve)`. How can I then retrieve the value? Its almost like I would want to do something like if it where possible `$($(keyVaultSecretToRetrieve))`.

I know my other option is to just run the command in a script using azure CLI which I tried but the build server says it does not have azure cli installed and I'd rather not mess with it and just wrap this up quickly. Not sure if there is some way to achieve what I want?

It's a windows build agent and the steps after this are mostly PowerShell. I wish the task just returns a data structure vs. dynamically named variables.... This is throwing me off it there is some trick I can do to make it work that I'm not aware of vs. just being forced to go the azure cli route or have the variable name coded in the variables name vs. as another variables.....

```yaml
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  displayName: Retrieve from keyvault
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(serviceConnection)
    KeyVaultName: $(keyVaultName)
    SecretsFilter: $(keyVaultSecretToRetrieve)
    RunAsPreJob: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you need to use nested variable: `$($(keyVaultSecretToRetrieve))`. There is no built-in feature can support this requirement.

To achieve your requirement, you can use the Variable Set  task from extension: [Variable Toolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks).

For example:

```
steps
- task: VariableSetTask@2
  inputs:
    variableName: NewVariable
    Value: '$($(keyVaultSecretToRetrieve))'
```

It will create a new variable based on the nested variable:`$($(keyVaultSecretToRetrieve))`. Then you can use the `$(NewVariable)` in the next tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in this way.

```
parameters:
- name: kvsubscription
  displayName: azure subscription for keyVault
  type: string
  default: AZURE_MY_DEVOPS

pool: 
  name: YOUR_POOL

stages:
- stage: CD
    jobs:
      - job: PrepareVariables
        displayName: 'Prepare Variables'
        steps:
        - script: |
            echo "settings variables ..."
            export YOUR_MASK="*"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MY_MASK;isoutput=true]$YOUR_MASK"
            export YOUR_KEYVAULT_NAME="company_land_app_keyvault"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MY_KV_NAME;isoutput=true]$YOUR_KEYVAULT_NAME"
          name: YourVars
        - bash: |
            echo $(YourVars.MY_MASK)
            echo $(YourVars.MY_KV_NAME)

      - job: GetCredentialsfromAzureKeyVault
        displayName: 'GetCredentialsfromAzureKeyVault'
        dependsOn: PrepareVariables
        variables:
          keyVaultName: $[ dependencies.PrepareVariables.outputs['VarsFromConfig.MY_KV_NAME'] ]
          keyVaultSecretToRetrieve: $[ dependencies.PrepareVariables.outputs['YourVars.MY_MASK'] ]
        steps:
          - task: AzureKeyVault@2
            displayName: 'Get keys from Azure Key Vault'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.kvsubscription }} #must be known before runtime -run of this pipeline - it could be in pipeline parameter 
              KeyVaultName: $(keyVaultName)
              SecretsFilter: $(keyVaultSecretToRetrieve)
              RunAsPreJob: true
          - script: |
              echo @scripts/select.sql
              echo "////"
            name: ValuesFromKeyVault
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?